# Return a promise with custom methods in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I need to return a custom js object that act as a promise, i.e., I can attach callbacks or error-callbacks when the deferred is either resolved or rejected. The thing I need some custom methods in this object, that can be run only when itself isn't "pending". It's something like:

```
foo = $.Deferred();

foo.a_method = function() {
    // do something only if "this" is resolved or rejected
    // throw an exception instead
};

return foo.promise();
```

The code above does not work, the promise returned does not have `a_method`, but only jQuery's defaults methods for promises. My idea now is:

```
var myMixin = {
    a_method: function() {
        // ...
    }
};

return $.extend(foo.promise(), myMixin);
```

That code works as expected, but it's not common to everybody (at least, I think) and it's not very straightforward to understand.

The reason I want it is that I have a lib that depends of some joined ajax requests(`$.when($.ajax('foo'), $.ajax('bar'))`) in order to execute well. So I do the
requests, attach some other callbacks and return a promise of this chain with "domain-specific" methods.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Does seem to work for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/zHxxv/ (never mind the globals)

Comment: please explain _why_ you're trying to achieve this - there may be a better overall approach.

Comment: @adeneo Only because you're misunderstanding the question, I think. [Here's what I think the OP is trying.](http://jsfiddle.net/zHxxv/1/) The only reason yours works in any way is because of the globals.

Comment: @lonesomeday - I get why it works, as foo is global, but it still works without globals -> http://jsfiddle.net/zHxxv/3/

Comment: But having a promise object and a deferred object in the same scope makes the promise object redundant, surely. The OP is looking to add a method to a particular promise object. His misunderstanding is that he is added it to the deferred object.

Comment: I'm struggling with the precise meaning of "... can be run ...", which seems to be key.

Comment: @Alnitak, I clarified this point on the question, hope it helps.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, my specific methods will throw an exception if `this`, which is a promise, is still "pending".

Comment: @adeneo, I really think you misunderstood the question. I don't want to return a deferred, but only a promise, because it can't resolve or reject a deferred, but only chain callbacks. Your last code works because `a_method` is part of `bar`, not `promise`.

Comment: I'm still struggling with the precise meaning of "... can be run ...". Are you looking for a method like `.done()` or `.then()` whose callback(s) are triggered from within the promise's parent Deferred, or are you looking for something that will be executed by an external command?

Comment: Something that will be executed by an external command.

Comment: In that case (and in the other case) you shouldn't be trying to add a method. Simply test `if(myPromise.state() === 'pending') {...}`.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, generally it is the best approach, but actually my lib do more than return a promise, it encapsulate a lot of code and internal state. The thing is I need to "lock" external code to only run my custom methods when the deferred itself is either "resolved" or "rejected".

Comment: that is still unclear - do you want your custom methods to be get run _automatically at the point of transition to those states_ ?  We could really do with an example of how this promise is going to be _used_.

Comment: Think about it as a normal promise, so I can chain callbacks. But also is a regular object, so I can run another methods. Those methods are not supposed to be run automatically after de deferred is resolved, but only when I want to (`var obj = A_Promise(); obj.my_method(); obj.then(() => console.log('callback executed'))`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Promise` object is not the same as the `Deferred` object. Calling `promise()` on a `Deferred` object creates a new `Promise` object. Since you added the function to the `Deferred` object, they aren't present on the `Promise`. So you need to add them to the `Promise` object itself.

In your `$.extend` call, you do precisely that. The syntax is a bit difficult, though, as you say. So you can use the simple syntax from above:

```
foo = $.Deferred().promise(); // store the promise object

foo.a_method = function() { // add the property to the Promise object
    // do something only if "this" is resolved or rejected
    // throw an exception instead
};

return foo; // return the Promise object
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a better way.

jQuery documentation for [Deferred.promise([target])](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) says :

> If target is provided, `deferred.promise()` will attach the methods onto it and then return this object rather than create a new one. This can be useful to attach the Promise behavior to an object that already exists.

Thus, you can define your own promise methods as follows :

```
var myPromiseMethods = {
    myMethod1: function() {
        ...
    },
    myMethod2: function() {
        ...
    },
    myMethod3: function() {
        ...
    }
};
```

Then, you can make your methods available as follows :

```
var dfrd = $.Deferred();
...
return dfrd.promise(myPromiseMethods).myMethod();
```

In general, you will want to write your methods something like this :

```
myMethod1: function() {
    var promise = this;
    //do something awesome here 
    return promise;
}
```

By returning `this` or `promise`, the method becomes chainable like the built-in Promise methods, eg :

```
var dfrd = $.Deferred();
...
return dfrd.promise(myPromiseMethods).myMethod().then(...);
```

### Example

You can define the object containing the custom method in any convenient scope. In this example, I simply name the object `é` (altGreen-E under Windows), which is compact, distinctive and unlikely to be used for other purposes.

So let's define an `invert()` method which reverses the sense of a promise - resolve becomes reject and reject becomes resolve.

```
var é = {
    invert: function() {
        var promise = this;
        return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
            promise.then(dfrd.reject, dfrd.resolve);
        }).promise();
    }
};

var dfrd = $.Deferred();
dfrd.promise(é).invert().done(function(str) {
    alert('done: ' + str);
}).fail(function(str) {
    alert('fail: ' + str);
});
dfrd.reject('*');
```

As you can see, the methods defined in `é` become available to any promise created with `dfrd.promise(é)`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R8Evv/)**